# An appropriate way to store neodymium magnets

Tags: magnetic-fields, laboratory-safety

Okay so I've bought a few small neodymium magnets to play around with, they're very powerful and I really like them, but I was wondering what's the actual best way of storing those magnets in a way that doesn't affect their magnetic fields or degrades them in any way.

I'm currently storing them stuck to one another, is it a good practice? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before modern rare earth permanent magnets, magnets required a 'keeper', metal bar that would shunt the flux between poles. This would prevent a loss in magnetization that could occur over time for materials like AlNiCo.

But with rare earth magnets like NdFeB keepers **are not required**. They will hold their strength, even when stacked.

Perhaps the most important thing regarding storage is to keep them stored in a secure place where small children cannot get to them. Swallowing these magnets can lead to pinching and internal bleeding of the gut. That's for small magnets.

For bigger rare earth magnets there is the danger of the magnet accelerating to high velocity, or metal objects around the magnet accelerating. Pinching forces can cut off circulation in fingers and bones can be broken! So these magnets require extreme care in handling to constantly make sure they are outside the range of other ferromagnetic objects. These magnets should be stored by themselves in sturdy, thick walled wooden boxes.

Comment: Good points about safety. Also - note the effect of temperature. When these magnets get warm they are more susceptible to having their magnetization reversed. See https://www.supermagnete.de/eng/faq/What-temperatures-can-magnets-sustain

Answer (score 0):

I just purchased a large-ish neodymium magnet. It is 2.75 inches in diameter, disk-shaped.  It also came with a thin disk of steel sheet metal the same diameter that is called a "striker plate."  It can be used in non-metal applications to get the magnet to attach. (e.g. if you want to use the magnet to hold a wooden cabinet door shut, you can attach the magnet to the frame and the striker to the door, which will cause the wooden door to "stick" to the magnet.)  The striker was separated from the magnet by a half-inch piece of styrofoam.

It didn't come with much in the way of instructions, however, the box said, "**Do not allow the striker to stick to the magnet or magnetic strength will be severely reduced**."   So, apparently you should not store the magnet near other metals. I'm trying to figure out if this rule also applies to other magnets (which I doubt because I see so many people store their magnets together) or if it is necessary to align the poles in a certain manner if magnets are stored together?